# Document Template with Managed Metadata Across Site Collections

Tags: 2013, site-collection, managed-metadata, list-template

We have a Document Template that has several managed metadata fields.  We would like to use this template across several (50+) site collections.  However, we get the following error when we try to create the library in a different site collection.

> Unable to open Lookup list '{f0b3822d-fa99-45d8-b54d-354cd3bdd12f}'.[Error was 0x81020026]

The list GUID in the error is for the "TaxonomyHiddenList" in the site collection where the template was created.

I have seen one suggestion that says to change the hidden list's GUID in the destination property bag, but that seems more like a hack than a solution.

Any suggestions on how we can make this template work across multiple site collections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error yesterday. Open the elements.xml that defines the SiteColumns and delete the WebID and ListId properties of the SiteColumn. This works fine because the TaxonomyHiddenList gets found without the correct GUID. There's no need for the properties to get the sitecolumn to work.

Comment: Where is the elements.xml?

Comment: Ok I see, I have to be more specific. What I did was the following. I worked with Visual-Studio and built the sitecolumns and the Content-type there by adding them with the help of the wizard (taking them from the working sitecollection). For the sitecolumns a new "elements.xml" got created in the VS-solution. I opened the "elements.xml" containing the definitions of my sitecolumns and deleted the properties of the sitecolumns(field) as mentioned above. Now I added those sitecolumns to a new content-type.

Comment: Afterwards I had a working content-type containing the managed-metadata-field, which I could deploy to all my sitecollections and added it to the libraries/lists.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the info.  If there is not a non-code solution I will mark your solution as the answer.

Comment: You could download your "template.stp" from template gallery and rename it to "template.cab" and open it with 7zip. you will find a manifest.xml inside. Inside this manifest.xml you will find the <field> where you can delete the wrong properties. Now´you can try to reupload the template to the template-gallery and give it a try.

Comment: I have done that, but the guid that points to the taxonomyhiddenlist does not exist there.  In fact, there is no reference to taxonomyhiddenlist at all.

Comment: Look for the TaxonomyFIELD or the guid, that would point wrong.